Lambda annotations: .NET Core 8 with NSwag
I went over https://towardsaws.com/access-swagger-ui-in-aws-lambda-via-api-gateway-deployed-with-the-serverless-framework-d80268ef1d79 document but this wouldn't help with .net 8 and Lambda Annotations. Since with lambda annotations we would be lambda function attribute instead of HttpGet, HttpPost and so on.
Any help would be appreciated. Or perhaps help in creating Swagger JSON/YML document which can then be later consumed by Redoc/NSwag.
I tried posting on AWS dotnet but to no avail. https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-dotnet/discussions/1744
I am now not sure how to proceed forward.

Welcome to SO. Please read [ask]. Please explain what lambdas, what annotations and please provide a [mre].

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
